# how to get data from current selected grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, stored-procedures

I have following `grid` in my `.aspx` page.

[image]

What i need to do:
When user clicks it should get `Company Name` `Product Name` `No. of records` from particular row and run the following procedure and download the excel file.

Following is my code:

**Stored Procedure:**

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[proc_getHistoryProduct]    
(    
@CompName nvarchar(max) = '',    
@ProdName nvarchar(max) = '',  
@noOfRecords int
)    
as    
begin    
if @ProdName = '' and @CompName = 'NULL'
begin  
select TOP (@noOfRecords) * from ProductDetail where (Product_Description like '%' +    @ProdName + '%' )
end  
else if @CompName = '' and @ProdName = 'NULL'
begin  
select  TOP (@noOfRecords) * from ProductDetail where (Shipper_Name like '%' + @CompName + '%' )
end  
end
```

**Code to download in excel:**

```
       protected void GridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        GridViewRow row = GridData.SelectedRow;
        int noOfRecords = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Text);
        string CompName = row.Cells[2].Text;
        string ProdName = row.Cells[1].Text;
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["UserHistoryProduct"];
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_getHistoryProduct", con);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000).Value = CompName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProdName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000).Value = ProdName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@noOfRecords", SqlDbType.Int).Value = noOfRecords;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        dt.Load(dr);
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
        Session["UserHistoryProduct"] = dt;

        DataTable Searchtable = (DataTable)Session["UserHistoryProduct"];

        ExportToExcel(dt);
    }
```

Can anybody tell me where am i going wrong?

**EDIT:**

```
   public void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt)
      {
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string filename = "HistoryProductDetail.xls";
            System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
            GridView dgGrid = new GridView();
            dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
            dgGrid.DataBind();

            //Get the HTML for the control.
            dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
            //Write the HTML back to the browser.
            //Response.ContentType = application/vnd.ms-excel;
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
            this.EnableViewState = false;
            Response.Write(tw.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have already given my tried code

Comment: @SMK i just want to know that where am i going wrong with my code,

Comment: @Sonam what is wrong with your code?

Comment: Are you getting records from query in datatable?

Comment: @JohnnyGraber Its doing nothing not even an error message. What i need to do is to run `[dbo].[proc_getHistoryProduct]` procedure when user clicks download button. and export the content in excel.
But its doing nothing.

Comment: @SainPradeep Yes sir if i pass default valued to stored proceduce i am getting the result.

Comment: it means problem in function ExportToExcel(). Please provide its code.

Comment: @SainPradeep I have edited my post with `ExportToExcel()` but that function is running correctly on my other pages.

Comment: am i reading the values correct fron data grid? by `int noOfRecords = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Text);
        string CompName = row.Cells[2].Text;
        string ProdName = row.Cells[1].Text;`

Comment: Have you checked "dt"? is it populated after executing this line of code dt.Load(dr);

Comment: debug the code and check that when you pass data table to function ExportToExcel() you have data in table.

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta yeah `dt` wasnt getting any records as my way of doing it was wrong.

Comment: @SainPradeep found the problem after debugging. Thanks for suggestion as i am such a naive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem at last!

What I needed to do is to call `OnClick="DownloadExcel_Click"` even on `<asp:LinkButton>` i.e `Download`

```
public void DownloadExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var downloadLink = (Control)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)downloadLink.NamingContainer;
        Label lblProduct = (Label)row.FindControl("lblprodname");
        string prodName = lblProduct.Text;
        Label lblCompany = (Label)row.FindControl("lblcompname");
        string compName = lblCompany.Text;
        Label lblRecords  = (Label)row.FindControl("lblrecords");
        int noOfRecords = Convert.ToInt32(lblRecords.Text);

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["UserHistoryProduct"];
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_getProductHistory", con);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProdName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000).Value = prodName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000).Value = compName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@noOfRecords", SqlDbType.Int).Value = noOfRecords;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
        }

        //dt.Load(dr);
        //dr.Close();
        con.Close();
        Session["UserHistoryProduct"] = dt;

        //DataTable Searchtable = (DataTable)Session["UserHistoryProduct"];

        ExportToExcel(dt);


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `SqlDataAdapter`

```
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(dt);
```

Instead of `SqlDataReader`

```
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dt.Load(dr);
    dr.Close();
```

I am not sure but it may help